# How can I prevent Sidekiq processing new jobs based on code version?

Tags: sidekiq, cloud-foundry, long-running-processes, continuous-delivery

We are deploying versions of a sidekiq worker to Cloud Foundry as part of a continuous delivery pipeline. We need to stop workers processing new jobs if they are no longer the latest version. So:

1. Worker v1 is running and performing a 30 min job.
2. We deploy v2 of the worker code.
3. v1 should continue with current jobs but not start any new ones.

CloudFoundry won't allow us to send [USR1](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Signals#usr1), so we need a solution that allows the workers to determine if they are the latest version before every job starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a new queue name in your V2 codebase

e.g/

```
class ImportantWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: :new_queue_name
  ....
end
```

and make sure you update your sidekiq config to reflect the new queue name

Comment: I'd agree.  Append a global version to all queue names in sidekiq.yml and your Workers.

Comment: Excellent; seems to be working well although we'll need to see what happens to a mounting pile of orphaned queues and come up with a plan for stopping sidetiq for creating more jobs...