# Prevent Sidetiq from scheduling new jobs based on {add logic here}

Tags: ruby, sidekiq, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery, sidetiq

We would like to stop Sidetiq from scheduling new jobs based on some condition. In our use case, [that there are no newer versions of the code running in another deployment/container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26138858/how-can-i-prevent-sidekiq-processing-new-jobs-based-on-code-version))

How can we add logic at the point Sidetiq is scheduling the job and prevent it from doing so?

Comment: @Mohamad Given that is also my question, I can assure you it's not. This is specifically about sideTiq, not sideKiq

Comment: Sorry about that. I didn't read the question carefully enough. Unfortunately there's no way for me to retract my close vote, but it should expire after some period of time.